# Sqlite3 operational error when trying to configure Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to configure Django on my Mac.

When executing "python manage.py syncdb" I get the following error (excerpted):

```
self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Possible causes I've been through and checked:

- Settings database section is pointing to a specific file:

  ```
  DATABASES = {

  'default': {

  'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
  'NAME': '%s/db/tumblog.sql' % PROJECT_ROOT, # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
  }
  }
  ```
- I'm running on virtualenv so it isn't a permission problem (I think).
- I closed the editor of settings.py before running the syncdb command.

Help?

Comment: How is `PROJECT_ROOT` set? What happens if you hard-code the full path?

Comment: Thanks - it got working when I hard coded it.

It was working like so:

import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite3 creates the `*.db` file automatically, but does not create the directory `db` where you expect the file `db/*.db`.

Does the directory `PROJECT_ROOT + '/db` exist and is it writable for you?

For sure, add a line

```
print '%s/db/tumblog.sql' % PROJECT_ROOT
```

to settings.py and run and see if the path is what you expect.